# Hooking with DLL a game hook

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

My DLL

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Funkcje.h"

WNDPROC originalProc;
LRESULT CALLBACK myHookProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwreason,
    LPVOID lpReversed)
{
    switch (fdwreason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        WNDPROC originalProc = SetWindowLongPtr(getToplevelWindows()[1], GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)myHookProc);
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK myHookProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT originalResult = originalProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // call original first
    if (uMsg == WM_PAINT)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        TextOut(hdc, 150, 150, L"TEST", 4);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }
    return originalResult;
}
```

Funkcje.h
http://pastebin.com/dc5t5H8s

I got a problem with (LONG_PTR)myHookProc
My compilers says that error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LONG' to 'WNDPROC'
I dont have any idea what i can do now. Without (LONG_PTR) my compiler says that he can't convert from 'LRESULT' to 'LONG'

Comment: You should explicitly cast the return value of SetWindowLongPtr: `originalProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(getToplevelWindows()[1], GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)myHookProc);`. Additionally if you want to access originalProc lateron you should not create another variable in the context of `case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature to:

```
LRESULT APIENTRY myHookProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

And the call to:

```
WNDPROC originalProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(getToplevelWindows()[1], GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)myHookProc);
```

Comment: I made it so http://pastebin.com/iBZJrfs2 and it dont work. It is only crashing my game.

Comment: Great. Problem solved. Your new problem has nothing to do with the error you described in this question. Please click on the checkbox near my answer to select it as the official solution.